# How to "try_lock" a recursive mutex to avoid crashes during destruction

Tags: c++, qt

I have a class that continuously makes rest calls with the use of a timer, the result of these rest calls gets sent back into the class and is processed afterwards.
The problem is, if this class's destructor gets called while this update process is going on this causes a crash.
I attempted to solve this with the use of a recursive mutex;

```
private:
    QTimer*                                      m_Timer = nullptr;
    std::recursive_mutex                         m_RecursiveMutex;
```

Placing one lock call on the destructor and a try_lock the start of the update function;

```
Class::~Destructor()
{
    std::lock_guard<std::recursive_mutex> lock(m_RecursiveMutex);
    m_Timer->stop();
    delete m_Timer;
}

void Class::UpdateSelf(GetInfoResponse res)
{
    if (m_RecursiveMutex.try_lock())
{
    ... do stuff
    }
}
```

However this doesn't seem to change anything as the update function still gets called and crashes the program, I have no idea what I'm doing wrong so I'd appreciate any input.

Comment: Does your code actually use threads?  I suspect you'd be far better off trying to understand the cause of the original crash rather than trying to fix things with a mutex.  As an aside, just make `m_Timer` a `QTimer` rather than a `QTimer *` -- there's really no need for the added complication of having to manage its heap allocation/deletion.

Comment: The fact that your object can be called regardless if it exists or not, tells me that mutex is not a problem here. Debug your code and analyze object lifetime. Why is it being used after destructor was already called?

Comment: It sounds like what you're doing wrong is deleting the `Class` object from thread A while thread B is still potentially able to access the `Class` object.  Simply adding a mutex won't solve that problem; you'll need to come up with a way to guarantee that thread B is no longer able to access the object before thread A deletes the object.  The big-hammer approach would be for thread A to tell thread B to exit, then thread A calls wait()/join() to block until thread B has actually exited, then thread A deletes the object, then (optionally) thread A spawns a new thread B afterwards.